# Difference in BigDecimal behavior

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have two pieces of code `new BigDecimal("1.240472701")` and `new BigDecimal(1.240472701)`. Now if i use compareTo method of java on both the methods then i get that they are not equal.

When i printed the values using `System.out.println()` method of java. I get different results for both the values. For example

```
new BigDecimal("1.240472701") -> 1.240472701

new BigDecimal(1.240472701) -> 1.2404727010000000664291519569815136492252349853515625
```

So i want to understand what could be reason for this?

Comment: not every decimal can be exactly represented in a float variable

Comment: @ScaryWombat: I think that what concerns the OP is that other than creating the digit from a different type, the same 'number' create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since user **thegauravmahawar** provided the answer from docs. Yes, it is because of **Scaling** in **BigDecimal** case.
So the values might seem equal to You but internally java uses Scaling while storing the value of BigDecimal type.

**Reason:** Scaling.

**Improvement:**

*You could call setScale to the same thing on the numbers you're comparing:*
 like this

```
new BigDecimal ("7.773").setScale(2).equals(new BigDecimal("7.774").setScale (2))
```

This will save you from making any mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer the Java doc of [`public BigDecimal(double val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) for this:

```
public BigDecimal(double val)
```

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal
>   which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary
>   floating-point value. The scale of the returned BigDecimal is the
>   smallest value such that (10^scale × val) is an integer.

- > The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One
  >   might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
  >   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
  >   a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
  >   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
  >   matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
  >   that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
  >   0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
- > The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates
  >   a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect.
  >   Therefore, it is generally recommended that the String constructor be
  >   used in preference to this one.
- > When a double must be used as a source
  >   for a BigDecimal, note that this constructor provides an exact
  >   conversion; it does not give the same result as converting the double
  >   to a String using the Double.toString(double) method and then using
  >   the BigDecimal(String) constructor. To get that result, use the static
  >   valueOf(double) method.

Answer (score 2):

The string `"1.240472701"` is a textual representation of a decimal value. The `BigDecimal` code parses this and creates a `BigDecimal` with the *exact* value represented in the string.

But the `double` `1.240472701` is merely a (close) approximation of that exact decimal value. `Double` cannot represent all decimal values exactly, so the exact value stored in the `double` differs slightly. If you pass that to a `BigDecimal`, it takes that differing value and turns it into an exact `BigDecimal`. But the `BigDecimal` only has the inexact `double` to go by, it does not know the exact text representation. So it can only represent the value in the `double`, not the value of the source text.

In the first case:

```
String --> BigDecimal
```

Because BigDecimal is *made* to exactly represent decimal values, that conversion is exact.

In the second case:

```
                  1          2
Source code text --> double --> BigDecimal
```

In the second case, precision is lost in the first conversion (1). The second conversion (2) is exact, but the input -- the double -- is an inexact representation of the source code text `1.240472701` (in reality, it is `1.2404727010000000664291519569815136492252349853515625`).

So: **never initialize a BigDecimal with a double**, if you can avoid it. Use a string instead.

That is why the first BigDecimal is exact and the second is not.